# File. exe in win cannot identify the file encoding, the file seems to be corrupted, what can be done?

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, notepad++

For some files, python's chardet library of `chardet.detect(f.read())['encoding']` returns None.

```
path=r"C:\A chinese novel.TXT"
with codecs.open(path, 'rb') as f:
    encoding=chardet.detect(f.read())
    print(encoding)
# RETURN {'encoding': None, 'confidence': 0.0, 'language': None}
```

I'll use `os.popen("file -bi \"%s\" | gawk -F'[ =]' '{print $3}'" % f).read()` view file coding, the compiler hints file encoding is `unknown - 8 bit`

'file xxx.txt' output `xxx.txt: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines (560), with CRLF line terminator`

Here's the GIf link to understand the situation: https://i.imgur.com/5kvmnRL.gif

However, Notepad++ can be opened normally, Notepad shows that the file is GB2312 encoding, and the character display is basically normal.

The file may become corrupted and so a mixed-encoding file that the chardet library cannot recognize?

Chatgpt suggested that I use iconv to re-encode the bad file, but the text editor (Notepad++) could not confirm which encoding the file is before opening. Is there a more reliable way to identify file encodings by python in windows10?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your specific programming problem is. Are you asking how to recover a corrupted file? (That would not be a programming-related question, which would make it off-topic here on Stack Overflow.) Or are you asking why you are unable to open a file in Python that you can open just fine in Notepad++? That would be a fine question, although you should probably [edit] your question to add a [mcve], which would include not only the Python code but also the actual contents of the file you're trying to open. Once you've edited the question to clarify, it can be re-opened.

Comment: @CodyGray Details have been added, but the problem has been closed. Do you need me to submit a new problem?

Comment: No, you should not submit a new question. You submitted this one for review 6 hours ago, after making the edits. That would normally result in it being reopened. It just takes some time, since all of the reviewers are volunteers. Since I happen to be a moderator (also a volunteer position), I'll just re-open this one manually instead of waiting out the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `chardet`: A very popular Python package for detecting encoding.
- `cchardet`: A Python module written in C++, similar to the chardet package.
- `File-magic`: A Python-wrapped libmagic library that recognizes file types and encodings.

```
import chardet
import cchardet
import magic

# chardet
with open('your_file_path', 'rb') as f:
    rawdata = f.read()
    result = chardet.detect(rawdata)
    encoding = result['encoding']
    print(encoding)

# cchardet
with open('your_file_path', 'rb') as f:
    rawdata = f.read()
    result = cchardet.detect(rawdata)
    encoding = result['encoding']
    print(encoding)

# file-magic
with magic.Magic() as m:
    file_type = m.id_filename('your_file_path')
    print(file_type)
```

After verification, **cchardet** recognition effect is good. It can successfully output the correct encoding format.